# robot.txt made Google stop indexing my site?

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

This is my robot:

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /feed/
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
Disallow: /wp-

Sitemap: http://chineselearnonline.com/sitemap.xml
```

Strange, I took that from a blog. But I noticed it made Google stopp indexing my WordPress site.

What is there problem there?

Comment: Assuming your site is http://www.chineselearnonline.com/, it's [still indexed on Google](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:chineselearnonline.com&oq=site:chineselearnonline.com&gs_l=hp.3...2997.10114.1.10641.15.14.1.0.0.2.152.1769.0j14.14.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.aJGTRTiNrpY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=d0997f8bfea33815&bpcl=37189454&biw=1196&bih=850).

Comment: @jmort253 Thanks,I think you are right. But strange, it used to appear on top of the search results when people typed: chinese learn online. Now it doesn't appear anymore. Recently, I moved to a new server. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Did you change your domain name? How about the links? For instance, if a result in google was `http://chineselearnonline.com/learn.html` and you changed it to `http://chineselearnonline.com/learn.php`, then you broke your links. ;(.

Comment: @jmort253 it used to be `http://chineselearnonline.com/v4` now it is `http://chineselearnonline.com/` is it possible that that was the cause?

Comment: I hate when I see this happen to people. Absolutely. Links are like your address. If you move to a new apartment and don't tell your friends, what happens? They go to your old apartment and find out you don't live there anymore. ;) So anyone on the Internet who linked to you are now linking to "Page no found"

Comment: You can fix this by editing your htaccess file to 301 redirect all of your v4 links to the new links, so if I go to /v4, I get redirected. This is like telling the guy at your old apartment, "Hey, if anyone  comes by to look for me, give him my new address." There's no guarantee the SEO will come back right away, or at all, but anyone who is linking to you will then no longer have broken links on their site.... Good luck!

Comment: @jmort253 Thanks! (if you post a answer I will tick it). But strange, this happens even if the site is in a subfolder and then is moved to the root folder?

Comment: The folder doesn't matter. What matters is the link. If the link you used to get to the about page is the same on your new server vs old, then the problem is something different. If the link is different, then you broke the Internet. ;)  By "link" I mean what you put in the address bar in your browser.

Comment: Isn't it *robot* **s** *.txt* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like, when you moved your site to another server, you may have inadvertently changed the base url that was used to access your site.  For instance, you mentioned that your site used to be accessed at http://chineselearnonline.com/v4, and now it is located at http://chineselearnonline.com/, without the v4.

Considering the site topic, it's possible that others have linked to you, either through blogging or other forms of sharing. If the search engines try to traverse your links and find that they're broken, your ranking in the search engines will decrease.

Note that this isn't the same as changing the location of the code on the actual server, just the url that points to that folder.

To resolve this, you may be able to edit your htaccess file to add a rule to 301 redirect all of the /v4 links to the new base url, so that any users, or search engine entities, would automatically redirect to the valid urls. This also tells the search engines that your content has permanently moved to the new location.

If your links disappeared in Google, establishing the 301 redirect may fix any broken links on the Internet and prevent everyone from needing to update the link physically in their blogs and websites. This should help build your SEO back up.

Answer (score 2):

You will need redirects, as is pointed out, but as for robots.txt, you're missing the `allow` line in robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

Disallow: /feed/
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
```

And this line makes no sense  `Disallow: /wp-` , so delete it.

Comment: I was thinking that the Allow should be in there but wasn't 100% sure. +1